# I want a file value or name when I upload a file in html javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, input-field

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #filee{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="" id="filee">
    <button onclick= "ftn()" id="btn">Choose a File</button>
    <span id="filename"></span> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let file = document.getElementById('filee');
        let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        let filename = document.getElementById("filename");
        function ftn(){
            file.click();
            let value = file.value;
            filename.innerText = value;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I'm getting value when i clicked button 2nd time. I want a value in span tag of my file when i click on button and open it. This giving value when i clicked again a button and show me previous value of file. Thanks if you get my point

Comment: The code does as it should, but probably not as you want. `ftn()` clicks the file input (which opens the dialog) but `let value = file.value` is set **immediately**. which is empty. Only the second time a value exists.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to know the name of the file whenever you've uploaded it to the browser. That means that you have to listen for  the `change` event on the file input.

```js
let file = document.getElementById('filee');
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let filename = document.getElementById("filename");

file.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const [file] = event.target.files
  filename.innerText = file.name;
});

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  file.click();
});
```

```css
#filee {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="" id="filee">
<button type="button" id="btn">Choose a File</button>
<span id="filename"></span>
```